# issue in image showing on full body

Tags: flutter

following is my code I have taken the screenshot of the image and showing here but the image is showing side border

```
class ResultImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Image image;

  // File file;
  ResultImage({Key key, this.image}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // file=File(image);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("View Image"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.share),
              tooltip: 'Share',
              onPressed: () => {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: image,

        ));
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Resolved issue by applying  `height: double.infinity,width: double.infinity` to fix your issue.

```
class ResultImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Image image;

  // File file;
  ResultImage({Key key, this.image}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // file=File(image);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("View Image"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.share),
              tooltip: 'Share',
              onPressed: () => {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Container(
          height: double.infinity,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: image,

        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this;

```
class ResultImage extends StatelessWidget {
final Image image;

// File file;
ResultImage({Key key, this.image}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// file=File(image);
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("View Image"),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.share),
          tooltip: 'Share',
          onPressed: () => {},
        ),
      ],
    ),
    body: Expanded(
      child: image,
    ));

    ),
   ),
  );

}
}
```

Comment: Try with my new answer

Answer (score 0):

Should set image fit as 'fit: BoxFit.fill', ex -

```
 @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text('Stack'),
          ),
          body:

            GestureDetector(
            child: Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  image: new DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('images/splash.png'),
                      fit: BoxFit.fill),

              ),

            ),

            onTap: () {},
          ),
        );
      }
```